# Send & read SMS  from PC via  Nokia Phones using java

Tags: java, symbian

Want to create application for send & read SMS from Symbian series 60 phone ie Nokia phones via PC  using Java. Is there any library?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question lacks detail. What did you try so far, what was the result? Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There sure is, http://gnokii.org/ It is a C based library, but you can write JNI wrappers to expose it as a Java API, and by the way its open source too :)

This is written purely in java, again opensource: http://smsj.sourceforge.net/ Sun stopped shipping the javacomm which allowed Java to communicate to serial ports, but they are no longer bundled with the Java releases, you may have to download it separately.